# Chrome Dev Tool の Performance タブにおいて、関数呼出フレームグラフの、関数それぞれの色は何を表す?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

Chrome Dev Tool で、自分のサイトのパフォーマンスを計っていました。

そこで、メインスレッドのフレームグラフの内容を見ていたのですが、ふと、関数それぞれに、別々の色が付いていることに気付きました。例えば下記の画像だと、 javascript の関数呼出は、基本的には水色ですが、たまに、緑だったり薄紅色だったりする様子です。

異なる色がついているからには、その関数について、パフォーマンスに影響してくる何かしらの情報を表しているのかと思っているのですが、いまいち、何によって色分けがなされているのか、分からないなと思っています。

## 質問

Chrome Dev Tool のフレームグラフにおける、それぞれの関数の色は何を表していますか?

[image: フレームグラフ]